# Weird bug in my CSS code making the text randomly get a huge "margin"

Tags: html, css, alignment, margin

I don't know why this is happening.

I have [this code here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Trufa/Yr6Dk/).

It works fine but "sometimes" (and many times in a row) for no apparent reason, this happens:

[image]

To all the `.box` class.

Sorry I have to share "all" my code but I have no idea why this is.

This is what it should look like:

[image]

I don't know if this is usual but id you want, you can download the two files from [here](http://www.box.net/shared/b6i335rguy) (HTML and CSS + Images) because in jsfiddle seems to work all of the times,

I don't know whether it matters or not but I'm using chrome (latest) on a mac.

**EDIT:** I seems to work fine in safari every time.

Thanks in advance!! Please ask for any clarification needed!

---

By the way my title is absolutely horrible, sorry! but I have no idea what the problem is so I can't really describe it, feel free to edit or comment any suggestion.

Comment: Looks ok in your fiddle. Have you added clear:both; to your container div?

Comment: No I hadn't, but I did now and it doen't seem to be working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `style.css`

1. Remove **`overflow:hidden`** on **`#container`**
2. Set **`overflow:hidden`** to the **`.box`**
3. Set **`float:left`** to the **`.box img`**
4. Set **`float:right`** to the **`.follow`**

new

```
#container {
    height:100%;
    width:520px;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    margin:20px 0 0 -250px;
}
.box {
    border:1px solid gray;
    height:200px;
    width:500px;
    float:left;
    margin:0px 0 20px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.box img {
    width:140px;
    height:140px;
    margin: 15px 0 0 15px;
    float:left;
}
.follow {
    /*outline:1px solid red;*/
    height:80px;
    width:260px;
    float:right;
    margin:25px 30px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had that wrong but it doesn't seem to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

To make your css cleaner, when you state styles for `.box:hover`, you don't need to redeclare things that already apply to `.box`. All `.box` styles are inherited by `.box:hover` .  (Example, how you have float:left on both).

That being said, this is almost certainly a `float` issue.  Adjust both the `float` and `clear` properties of the two inner divs, the outer div, and the img to see if you learn anything from that.  It's difficult to give help when the problem doesn't occur in the fiddle.

Comment: I fixes the `.box:hover` thanks!! I've tried quite a lot of combinations of float and clear and nothing seems to solve it! (if you want of course!!!!) but you can download the file from here: http://www.box.net/shared/b6i335rguy